# mock does not get pick up mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I have a question about mockk and wonder where i set up wrongly. here are my code snippet.

```kotlin
// my unit test
val myObject = spyk<Manager>()

// Define behavior for the property
val mockOK = mockk<Result>()
every { mockOK.id } returns "aaa"
every { mockOK.status } returns SessionStatus.OK
every { mockOK.timestamp } returns 123
every { mockOK.isValid() } returns true

every { myObject.ok } returns mockOK

// Use the mocked property
val result = myObject.ok
assertEquals("aaa", result.id)  // this is good 
assertEquals(true, result.isValid())  // this is good. 

val actual = myObject.getResult() 
assertEquals("aaa",actual.id) //this failed 


// my class 
class Manager{
    var ok : Result = Result()
    var notOk: Result = Result()
    fun getResult() = if (ok.isValid()) { ok } else notOk
}
```

I was able to mock it correctly inside `myObject` but when I called `getResult()` which should return the instance variable `ok`, just like `myObject.ok` but it did not return as expected. I am getting a different object. did i have mockk set up correctly?

Comment: How does it fail? Is an exception thrown because some access failed or is the assertion failing. If the later is the case, what is the message telling you?
Also your getResult method seems syntactically broken. Either use `=` and remove the return keyword, or use a block with `{ ... }` but not a mix of both. Also, the if statement is incomplete. What does `getResult` return in case the result is not valid? I think your method might be a unit method, because your `if`-statement is nor an expression and does not actually return `ok`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your mockOk directly from the getResult() call

```
// given this data
every { myObject.getResult() } returns mockOK

val expected = "aaa"

// when this happens in the code
val actualId = myObject.getResult().id

// then this is expected
assertThat(actualId).isEqualTo(expected)
```

I also suggest to reformat the styling of your test in order to be more readable.
Let me know if this resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it does not work to mock the property with only an initializer in a mockk-spy. There are several ways to solve this:

**Option 1**: You can replace `ok` with a function

```
fun ok(): Result = Result()
```

or add a getter and setter like this

```
var ok: Result = Result()
    get() { return field }
    set(value) { field = value }
```

This way, for some reason, the spy will return your mocked `ok` value inside `getResult`.

**Option 2**: You intend to create a partial mock with `ok` mocked and `getResult` calling the original code. Instead of using a spy, you can alternatively use a mock for this:

```
val myObject = mockk<Manager> {
    every { ok } returns mockOK
    every { getResult() } answers { callOriginal() }
}
```

This way, your mocked `ok` value will also be picked up by the original implementation of `getResult`.

**Option 3**: Why change the value of `ok` through mocking when it is a public mutable property? You can as well just set it with an assignment:

```
myObject.ok = mockOK
```